# Reading positional parameters using PHP

Tags: php, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I am using a .php page just like a shell script. The only problem is that I do not know how to pass the positional parameters to PHP page.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$myfile="balexp.xml";
```

The following does not work in this php page and does work in the shell script.

```
myvar=$1
```

How do I pass variables to a php page?

Comment: make sure `register_argc_argv` is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$myfile=$argv[1];
```

See [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) for more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make use of the array `$argv`.

Run the following CLI PHP passing it command line arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

On running:

```
$ chmod u+x a.php
$ ./a.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "./a.php"
}

$ ./a.php foo
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "./a.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}

$
```

Clearly `$argv[0]` contains the name of the script, `$argv[1]` contains the first command line argument.

The [**manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) has all the details on how to handle command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `register_argc_argv` turn on, you can use `$argv`

```
your_script.php haha hehe

<?
echo $argv[0]    <-- your_script.php 
$myfile=$argv[1];
echo $myfile;    <-- return haha
?>
```

more details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Answer (score 1):

You pass positional parameters via the $argv convention. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php.